# Footer nav not centered

Tags: css, css-float, text-align

I'm having trouble getting my footer nav to centre properly. It's very simple but just not doing what it's supposed to.

```css
.main-footer li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 2em;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li>&copy; Copyright Acme Industries 2019</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

I've tried adding `display: block` or `display: inline-block` in both css selectors but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Thanks, Kate

Comment: footer to center ? or the content of the footer to be centered inside the footer ?

Comment: You'll want to use `flex`; there is a decent flexbox generator here (http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) though there are more: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flexbox+generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With float, you are forcing elements to be pulled towards the left. 
Use display:inline-block to make the element in center, as parent is already text-align:center

```css
.main-footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  list-style-type:none
}

.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 2em;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li>&copy; Copyright Acme Industries 2019</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all. NEVER use `float` for layout purposes. It messes up your content and it starts a snowball effect in your CSS.

`flex` is the way to go -> [flexbox MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) ( and other links )

Use `align-items: center` to align your items **vertically** and `justify-content: center` to align them **horizontally**.

Also, use `box-sizing: border-box` so the padding of the footer will be 'included' in it's `100%` width and you don't have a scroll overflow on x-axis.

```css
.main-footer li {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 2em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li>&copy; Copyright Acme Industries 2019</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: You're *supposed* to use `float` for layout purposes! It was the *original* layout property! What you should be saying is not to mix `float` and `flex` in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `flexbox`:

```css
.main-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 2em;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-footer li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li>&copy; Copyright Acme Industries 2019</li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to go the flex way, just change the display property of your UL element.

Something like this:

```css
.main-footer ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-footer li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 2em 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li>&copy; Copyright Acme Industries 2019</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ul` as the flex container and remove the left and right padding from the `footer` container to ensure it's centered. The padding can be added to the `ul` instead.

Without flexbox, set the `li` elements to `display: inline-block`.

```css
.main-footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 2em 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-footer ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-footer li {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.main-footer li:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li>&copy; Copyright Acme Industries 2019</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```